Django/Dash - injected script not executed but no errors
I'm trying to create a text area in a dash app which shall function as status window for the user. Updates shall be sent to the window via messaging (ws, channels, redis).
    html.Div(style={'flex': '0 0 auto', 'padding': '0px', 'boxSizing': 'border-box'}, children=[
        dcc.Textarea(
            id='log-window',
            style={'width': '100%', 'height': '400px', 'resize': 'none'},
            readOnly=True),
        html.Script("""
            console.log('logging script loaded successfully!');
            window.onload = function() {
                var logWindow = document.getElementById('log-window');
                if (logWindow) {
                    var socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/logs/');

                    socket.onmessage = function (event) {
                        var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
                        logWindow.value += data.message + '\\n';
                    };

                    socket.onopen = function () {
                        console.log('WebSocket connection opened');
                    };

                    socket.onerror = function (error) {
                        console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
                    };

                    socket.onclose = function () {
                        console.log('WebSocket connection closed');
                    };

                } else {
                    console.error('logWindow element is null');
                };
            };
        """)
    ]),

The text area is created successfully but the injected script from above for starting the WebSocket connection is not executed. Nevertheless, the script is visible when inspecting the source code in the web browser. The console does not produce any error or hint. The text area is part of an iframe which holds the above dash application and allows scripts.
The script was executed when I included it in the app_view.html but there were diffuclties in obtaining the logWindow element which was always reported as null. This is why I included the script in the above dash app using html.Script("""......""") but it's not executed.
Calling the script via html.Script(src='/assets/logging.js') didn’t change anything - it's not loaded and not executed.
Using another web server (Daphne, Uvicorn) didn't help either.
When wrapping the script in a simple html structure and then saving it to a .html file and opening it with the browser, the script executes just fine.
Hence, I suspect that the Dash/Django Framework is responsible for not executing the Javascript but how can i change this?
I'm using Firefox 129.02, Django 5.0.7, Dash 2.9.3, channels 4.1.0, channels-redis 4.2.0, python3.12. The web server is Django runserver.
